# How to use or resolve enum types with graphql-tools?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I cannot find anywhere in the `graphql-tools` documentation how one should go about utilizing `enum` types in schemas that are fed to `makeExecutableSchema`. Anyone have a clue how this done?

Example code:

```
enum Color {
  RED
  GREEN
  BLUE
}

type Car {
  color: Color!
}
```

What would the resolver for `Color` look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You wouldn't write a resolver for `Color`. Here's a simple, runnable example:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } = require('graphql-server-express');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const app = require('express')();

const carsData = [
  {color: 'RED'},
  {color: 'GREEN'},
  {color: 'BLUE'},
];

const typeDefs = `
  enum Color {
    RED
    GREEN
    BLUE
  }
  type Car {
    color: Color!
  }
  type Query {
    cars: [Car!]!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    cars: () => carsData,
  }
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));

app.listen(3000);
```

Run a `cars` query (`{cars {color}}`) in [GraphiQL](http://localhost:3000/graphiql) and you will see a color returned for each car in our data. Now, change one of the values in the **data** (not the Enum definition) to a color you didn't define, like `PINK`. Run the query again and you will see an error message like:

```
"Expected a value of type \"Color\" but received: PINK"
```

This works with resolvers too, so if I override the data by adding a resolver for Car like this:

```
Car: {
  color: () => 'RED'
}
```

The query will show all the cars with RED as their color. If you change the value returned by the resolver to `BLACK`, the query will error out again.

Enums are just a way of enforcing that whatever value a particular field resolves to is within the set of values you define.

Comment: OK, so this simply works out of the box. It was not knowing how the values of the enums are determined that had me thinking I had to set up a resolver for these guys, then I didn't see anything in the docs about it. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 7):

By default, the enum is represented with the same string : `enum Color { RED }` is `'RED'`.
You can override this by adding a resolver to the enum:

```
Color: {
  RED: '#ff0000',
  GREEN: '#00ff00'
},
Query {...
```

More info: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars.html#internal-values