# Can't custom value of graphql enum

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I have looked this question: [How to use or resolve enum types with graphql-tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056347/how-to-use-or-resolve-enum-types-with-graphql-tools)

And, this doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#internal-values

Now, I want to custom the value of graphql `enum`.

`typeDefs.ts`:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  enum Device {
    UNKNOWN
    DESKTOP
    HIGH_END_MOBILE
    TABLET
    CONNECTED_TV
  }

  type CampaignPerformanceReport {
    campaignNme: String!
    campaignId: ID!
    device: Device
  }

  type Query {
    campaignPerformanceReports: [CampaignPerformanceReport]!
  }
`;
```

`resolvers.ts`:

```js
import { IResolvers } from 'graphql-tools';
import { IAppContext } from './appContext';

export const resolvers: IResolvers = {
  Device: {
    UNKNOWN: 'Other',
    DESKTOP: 'Computers',
    HIGH_END_MOBILE: 'Mobile devices with full browsers',
    TABLET: 'Tablets with full browsers',
    CONNECTED_TV: 'Devices streaming video content to TV screens',
  },
  Query: {
    async campaignPerformanceReports(_, __, { db }: IAppContext) {
      return db.campaignPerformanceReports;
    },
  },
};
```

As you can see, I custom the value of `Device` enum in the resolver.

`db.ts`: a fake db with datas

```js
enum Device {
  UNKNOWN = 'Other',
  DESKTOP = 'Computers',
  HIGH_END_MOBILE = 'Mobile devices with full browsers',
  TABLET = 'Tablets with full browsers',
  CONNECTED_TV = 'Devices streaming video content to TV screens',
}

export const db = {
  campaignPerformanceReports: [
    {
      campaignId: 1,
      campaignNme: 'test',
      device: Device.DESKTOP,
    },
  ],
};
```

I also made an integration test for this:

```js
 test.only('should query campaign performance reports correctly with executable graphql schema', async () => {
      const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
      console.log(printSchema(schema));
      const server: ApolloServerBase = new ApolloServer({ schema, context: { db } });
      const { query }: ApolloServerTestClient = createTestClient(server);
      const res: GraphQLResponse = await query({ query: Q.campaignPerformanceReports });
      expect(res).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
        Object {
          "data": Object {
            "campaignPerformanceReports": Array [
              Object {
                "campaignId": "1",
                "campaignNme": "test",
                "device": "DESKTOP",
              },
            ],
          },
          "errors": undefined,
          "extensions": undefined,
          "http": Object {
            "headers": Headers {
              Symbol(map): Object {},
            },
          },
        }
      `);
    });
```

As you can see, the result of snapshot testing. The value of `device` field is still **"DESKTOP"**, I expected the value should be **"Computers"**

Dependencies version:

```
"apollo-server": "^2.9.3",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.9.3",
"graphql": "^14.5.4",
```

The minimal repo: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/custom-scalar-and-enum

Comment: You are misunderstanding custom values. These will be the values _on the server side_ not on the client side. GraphQL will always return the enum value's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal values you specify for a GraphQL enum are just that -- internal. This is stated in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#internal-values):

> **These don't change the public API at all**, but they do allow you to use that value instead of the schema value in your resolvers

If you map the enum value `DESKTOP` to the internal value `Computers`, only the *behavior of your resolvers will be affected*. Specifically:

- If a field takes an argument of the type `Device` and the argument is passed the value `DESKTOP`, the value actually passed to the resolver function will be `Computers`.
- If a field itself has the type device and we want to return `DESKTOP`, inside our resolver, we will need to return `Computers` instead.

Take for example a schema that looks like this:

```
type Query {
  someQuery(device: Device!): Device!
}
```

If you **don't** specify internal values, our resolver works like this:

```
function (parent, args) {
  console.log(args.device) // "DESKTOP"
  return 'DESKTOP'
}
```

If you **do** specify internal values, the resolver looks like this:

```
function (parent, args) {
  console.log(args.device) // "Computers"
  return 'Computers'
}
```

The resolver is the only thing impacted by providing internal values for each enum value. What **doesn't** change:

- How the enum value is serialized in the response. Enum values are **always** serialized as strings of the enum value name.
- How the enum value is written as a literal inside a document. For example, if querying the above same field, we would **always** write: `{ someQuery(device: DESKTOP) }`
- How the enum value is provided as a variable. A variable of the type `Device` would **always** be written as `"DESKTOP"`.

**NOTE:** While the question pertains specifically to Apollo Server, the above applies to vanilla GraphQL.js as well. For example, this enum

```js
const DeviceEnum = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'Device',
  values: {
    UNKNOWN: { value: 'Other' },
    DESKTOP: { value: 'Computers' },
    HIGH_END_MOBILE: { value: 'Mobile devices with full browsers' },
    TABLET: { value: 'Tablets with full browsers' },
    CONNECTED_TV: { value: 'Devices streaming video content to TV screens' },
  }
})
```

will still behave as described above.

Comment: It's very helpful. But how should I resolve the enum type `Device` to a new value for public API? This is my question. I can't define the enum like `Tablets with full browsers` directly. Because it seems that graphql does't support this syntax. It's invalid.

Comment: Yes, GraphQL enum values cannot have spaces. There is no mechanism for something like that server-side. You would have to map the enum values to whatever labels client-side. Or don't use enums. You can return an object type that has a label property, for example.